# Can I install Windows 7 on a MacBookPro2,2 running Snow Leopard (10.6.8) with Boot Camp?

Tags: windows-7, mac, osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp

The installation & setup guide says I need a MacBook Pro introduced in 2007 or later. I have a MacBook Pro introduced in October 2006. I have my Snow Leopard installation disk, and can obtain a Windows 7 full system version from Best Buy. I don't want to spend the money if it won't work. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: If you want true "dual boot" you need BootCamp. If you want a hybrid dual boot (I think you still need BootCamp) you can use Parallels (you can run a dual boot with Windows simultaneously - incredible software!). Finally, you can run, for example, VirtualBox and have Windows 7 as a "guest" OS. You run it in its own window at the same time as Snow Leopard and it can use system resources.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not too late in answering your question.
I have a MacBookpro 2.33 Core 2 Duo dating from Oct. 2006. I have been running Windows on it since day one.  When I got this Mac it came with OS X 10.4. I was using Bootcamp beta and Windows XP. Since I have used 10.5 and later 10.6.8.
Today I'm still running Win7 x64 under Bootcamp 3.3.  It works like a charm.  I know many friends who bought genuine PCs in 2006 who have been replacing their computer a while ago. I'm approaching 9 years of use with my Mac without a major glitch. So far only the Superdrive has gone berzerk. I have added 2Gb of RAM and changed the HDD from 160 Gb 5400 rpm to a 512 Gb 7400 rpm.  As I don't want to change for Win 8.1 I have installed a brand new 512 Gb SSD to give my Mac a second youth. At this point my only deception is that I have not (yet) been able to activate AHCI under Windows to even further improve the performances of the SSD.

04/13/2015 edit : I've now successfully activated AHCI on the Bootcamp Win7 x64 partition. I had to do some tweaking in the Mac OS X side of the machine (namely uninstalling the Paragon NTFS driver) to succeed but it finally worked well. I've now a MacBook Pro (2006) with SL 10.6.8 + Win7 x64 and a functional SSD;  The whole runs like a charm even being 9 years old.

There is no doubt in my mind that Bootcamp is a great software if you want to run Windows 7 while still enjoying the Mac side of the IT world. Your money will be well spent.  Cheers. (Note : stay (far) away from Win 8.1 because this is not the same story...)

Comment: Parallels or VMware only for me - Bootcamp does voodoo magic to the EFI boot ...

Comment: I gave up and got a Windows PC from my son-in-law. He had a "spare" because he had updated to a newer computer. I'm now able to run TurboTax on Windows 7. That was my goal, and I;m there. If I had to do something on my Snow Leopard system, I'd probably use VMware.